# subprocess call with args is only reading first arg

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to automate nmap scans and I am using the subprocess module to do so. I am pretty much passing three variables to subprocess.call and having the command be run. Here is my code

```
import subprocess

TOOL = 'nmap'
joined = '-p1 5000'
target = 'localhost'

subprocess.call([TOOL, joined, target], shell=True)
```

This should lead to `nmap -p1 5000 localhost` being ran on my system which is a valid command, however, the call method seems to only be recognizing TOOL(nmap) and it just prints out the options for nmap. Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

Comment: I think you need to separate `joined`, since it will be quoted and interpreted as a single argument otherwise.

Comment: @Aankhen I have tried that as well as other nmap options like -A or -v and they haven't worked either

Comment: You can try this `subprocess.call([TOOL, 'p1 5000', target], shell=False)`

Comment: As Kishan said, you shouldn’t need to set `shell=True`, since you’re not using any of its features; you can use [`distutils.spawn.find_executable`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.spawn) to locate `nmap` if you need to.

Comment: @Kishan Unfortunately, I need them passed from variables and that does not work as well

Comment: Yes @UCProgrammer then pass `joined= 'p1 5000'` and `shell=False`

Comment: use full path: /usr/bin/nmap

Comment: @hootnot, that has nothing at all to do with the issue. `subprocess` behaves equivalently to `execlp()`, doing PATH lookups; moreover with `shell=True`, the shell it starts is doing another lookup layer as well.

Comment: no I see that now , I should have read it better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have `nmap` installed but you need set `shell=False` and split parameters:

```
import subprocess

TOOL = 'ls'
joined = '-a -l'
target = '/tmp'

print(subprocess.call([TOOL, *joined.split(), target], shell=False))
```

Comment: That is correct. Thank you. I guess I need to look at the difference between shell=True and shell=False.

Comment: @UCProgrammer, with `shell=True`, the arguments `['sh', '-c']` get prepended to your list. That's literally all it does.

Comment: @UCProgrammer, ...however, only the argument immediately after `-c` is parsed by `sh` as a shell script; other arguments are parsed as *arguments to that script*.

Comment: We already have a lot of instances of this question in the knowledge base -- it should have been closed as a dupe, not answered.

Comment: I also strongly advise against using `split()` in this context. Much, **much** less error-prone to explicitly pass `'-a', '-l'`; otherwise, you get into serious trouble when trying to process a filename with spaces. If you **must** use a split function, use `shlex.split()`, not `string.split()`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you for the feedback. I will see what I can do about this.